# Sails grunt watch - Warning: Cannot read property 'bigint' of undefined Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js, warnings

I run sails on current project, just copied current project to new macbook high sierra and suddenly shown this error when running task grunt and edit asset files.

Sails version: 1.0.2

Grunt-cli version: 1.2.0

Grunt version: 1.0.3

Npm vesion: 6.1.0

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "assets/styles/project/_colors.scss" changed.
Running "less:dev" (less) task
>> 1 stylesheet created.

Running "sass:dev" (sass) task

Running "sync:dev" (sync) task
**Warning: Cannot read property 'bigint' of undefined Use --force to continue.**
```

When i run trace for this problem will show this

```
Warning: Cannot read property 'bigint' of undefined Use --force to continue.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bigint' of undefined
  at Object.stat (fs.js:795:37)
  at Object.stat (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/promised-io/promise.js:709:17)
  at processPair (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt-sync/tasks/sync.js:143:28)
  at /Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt-sync/tasks/sync.js:52:16
  at Array.map (<anonymous>:null:null)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt-sync/tasks/sync.js:37:38)
  at Array.map (<anonymous>:null:null)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt-sync/tasks/sync.js:29:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:252:15)
  at Object.thisTask.fn (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:70:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:294:30)
  at Task.runTaskFn (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:244:24)
  at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:293:12)
  at /Users/erwinsetiawan/Works/Project/review-portal/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:220:11
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

It nothing happen when run this project to another laptop old el capitan and windows

Anyone can help me to solve di problem?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be fixed in [grunt-sync 0.8.0](https://github.com/tomusdrw/grunt-sync/releases/tag/v0.8.0). I suggest updating the grunt-sync package.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in sails-hook-grunt@4.0.1 (see https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4470 for more information)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade from node 10.5.0 to node 10.4.1 fix this problem, so probably current grunt version not yet supported the newest node version.